# ajax-datatables-rails having issues searching in datatable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatable

I have three models, `School`, `Student`, and `Exams`. Although the associations can be assumed relatively easily, here is what the model structure looks like:

```
class School < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :students
end
```

.

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :school
    has_many :exams
end
```

.

```
class Exam < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :student
end
```

The table actually displays correctly, but I cannot use the search feature because it gives me the common error message with this:

> DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error. For more
> information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

I can't figure out what's wrong with my joins statement. I mean it works fine as far as displaying the content, but the search feature doesn't work. I know that `ajax-datatable-rails` [Github](https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails) page shows how to use nested attributes, and nested attributes work just fine when I have just *two* nested attributes.

For example, this works:

```
Student.joins(:school).where(schools: {school_name: "Hello World"})
```

but not if I nest it down one more layer using this:

```
Exam.joins(student: :school}).where(schools: {school_name: "Hello World"})
```

In fact, I cannot even just simply use `Exam.joins(student: :school)` because it, again, displays correctly, but cannot be searched.

This has to be something specific to `ajax-datatables-rails` I would imagine, since the table displays correctly but cannot be searched.

Comment: You can setup `has_one :school, through: :student` in Exam and `has_many :exams, through: :students` in School. This will let you do `School.include(:exams)` or `Exam.include(:school)`.

Comment: While I can call that and it works just fine from the rails console, for some reason `ajax-datatables-rails` still doesn't like it and throws me an error when trying to search.